# target first occurence of element css

Tags: css

I'd like to target the first occurence of the `<a>` element in this list, first-child doesn't seem to work because it selects all the children `<a>` s. Any ideas?

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-1 current-cat">
    <a title="View all posts filed under Basket" href="http://machinas.com/wip/esprit/wiki/wordpress/?cat=1">Basket</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-19">
            <a title="View all posts filed under Article List" href="http://machinas.com/wip/esprit/wiki/wordpress/?cat=19">Article List</a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li class="cat-item cat-item-20">
                    <a title="View all posts filed under Mobile" href="http://machinas.com/wip/esprit/wiki/wordpress/?cat=20">Mobile</a>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li class="cat-item cat-item-21">
                            <a title="View all posts filed under Current" href="http://machinas.com/wip/esprit/wiki/wordpress/?cat=21">Current</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="cat-item cat-item-22">
                    <a title="View all posts filed under Desktop" href="http://machinas.com/wip/esprit/wiki/wordpress/?cat=22">Desktop</a>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li class="cat-item cat-item-23">
                            <a title="View all posts filed under Current" href="http://machinas.com/wip/esprit/wiki/wordpress/?cat=23">Current</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to target the first li and then it's anchor link

```
ul li:first-child a {
 /* your styles here */
}
```

It difficult to be more specific but if you were referring to the `children` ul you can make it

```
 ul.children > li:first-child a {
     /*your styles here */
    }
```

If you mean this

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-1 current-cat">
    <a title="View all posts filed under Basket" href="http://machinas.com/wip/esprit/wiki/wordpress/?cat=1">Basket</a>
```

The css would be

```
li.cat-item.cat-item-1.current-cat > a {
/*styles */
}
```

Comment: Wont work...`ul li:first-child a {` would select all hypelinks inside first li

Comment: All hyperlinks inside all first `li` then yes, which is why I added extra examples for clarity based on OP's HTML.

Comment: even `ul > li a:first-of-type {` would have work then

Comment: No, that would match all `a` tags that as they are all first children of `li`. There is only one `a` tag per `li` so they are all `first-children or type`

Answer (score 0):

If by "this list" you mean the root, you could do:

```
.current-cat > a
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using jQuery on your site, but if so, you can work with jquery and do this.

```
$("a").first().attr("title");
```

Etc.

As I said, it depends if you're using jQuery and it can be used for what you'd like to do, but since you didn't specify what you plan to do with the result, it's hard to assume otherwise.